# View Not Found when deployed on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a page that loading perfectly locally.

[image]

I deploy same code to Heroku, I got this

[image]

I can't really check if the actual file is there, since Heroku is not allow SFTP.

But I have that file locally.

[image]

Do I need to clear cache or something ?

What shold I look into ?

---

I've tried

```
heroku run php artisan view:clear
```

I got

```
Running php artisan view:clear on ⬢ umaket-technology... up, run.6160 (Free)
Compiled views cleared!
```

**Same result !**

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` might solve the issue - clears cached views, etc

Comment: I tried that, I got `Compiled views cleared!`, but still showing same result.

Comment: Can't you `cd` and `ls` the files via command line? I'm not familiar with Heroku.

Comment: Furthermore, what's your ENV look like? Do you have a key set? Is it set to production?

Comment: Nope, you can not really do anything like that. It's not a VM or VPS that we can SSH in and see the file structure.

Comment: You can't BASH in? i.e. `heroku run bash`

Comment: How is .env is related to view not found, and yes I have APP_KEY configured.

Comment: @MikeBarwick : I didn't know you can do that. Wow. this is cool. :)

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`? And different environments have different security protocols, last I checked.

Comment: Yeah, I saw a file spelled wrong with an uppercase `Driver.blade.php`

Comment: I know that is the errors, but I still trying to find out what is the cause of my local and my Heroku files system different ?

Comment: I check my `git status` - it's clean. There is nothing more to push to Heroku.

Comment: Sounds to me like there might be some cached views/folder structure or something along those lines. `composer dump-autoload` might solve this.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for Heroku but I ran into a similar issue when I was developing locally (Mac) and pushed to my server (Debian). The issue ended up being case sensitive view names, Mac ignored them but Debian didn't so it wasn't able to find the views.

Hopefully that will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

like @WhereisJefe says :

check your view

```
@extends('check here case')
```

check your controller

```
return view('check here case')
```

Answer (score 0):

My project work fine on local system. 
But when i deployed on the server got this issue.

thanks to **JeffBeltran**
after spending 3 4 hours i get error .

My error was just the **dir** name was **H**ome and in path i used **home** it works fine on my local environment . 
I just change **h** to **H** and works fine for me

Code with error

```
Route::get('/home', function(){
return view('home.index');
```

updated code without error

```
Route::get('/home', function(){
    return view('Home.index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question seems to be very old, it still does not seem to have a satisfactory answer.

I had a similar experience and was able to find the solution here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/heroku-laravel-views-not-found.

To summarize; **Do not run any caching in your post-deploy scripts**

In my case, I had the following in my `composer.json` file:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "@php artisan clear-compiled",
            "@php artisan cache:clear",
            "@php artisan optimize",
            "@php artisan migrate --force"
        ]
```

The line **"@php artisan optimize"** was the culprit.

So I changed it to:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "@php artisan clear-compiled",
            "@php artisan cache:clear",
            "@php artisan config:clear",
            "@php artisan migrate --force"
        ]
```

That fixed the issue for me, and I hope it does for any other person that may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is no marked answer for this but coming from laravel 8 and the number of times I have had this error, it is usually because my blade file name is different from the name I have in my controller, specifically in the `view()` helper function. For example:

If my blade file is "`Stackoverflow.blade.php`" then in my controller, i have something like `return view('stackoverflow');` This will throw an error not found on heroku for example. Reason being that there there is a difference in the capitalisation.

`S` : `Stackoverflow` and `s` : `stackoverflow`

So such can be the reason why you can get that type of error on heroku